# RethinkDB losing data after restarting server

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I save my data on RethinkDB Database. As long as I dont restart the server, all is well. But when I restart, it gives me an error saying database doesnt exist, although the folder and data does exist in folder ***rethinkdb_data***. What is the problem ?

Comment: How are you starting rethinkdb? The `--directory` option lets you specify what folder your data is stored in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost certainly not losing data, you're just starting RethinkDB without pointing it to the data. Try the following:

- Start RethinkDB from the directory that contains the `rethinkdb_data` directory.
- Alternatively, pass the `-d` flag to RethinkDB to point it to the directory that contains `rethinkdb_data`. For example, `rethinkdb -d /path/to/data/directory/rethinkdb_data`